# Angular 4+ Detect click in Div or nested child Divs and distinguish from other outside Divs

Tags: angular, elementref

I have seen many Angular 2 pages that loop through a hierarchy of nativeElements.  They don't work in Angular 4, 5, ...
I need to add a directive to a "workspace" DIV.  There will be other Divs that are parent of workspace and others are child DIVs nested to any level.
This directive must detect a mouse click for the "workspace" div OR any of the nested divs and I must determine that it is in fact a nest child or the workspace -- and NOT some other div above workspace or outside workspace.

This is derived from one of the many examples on the web:

```
    import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[shMonitorInfoClicks]'
})
export class MonitorInfoClicksDirective {
  public elementRef;

  constructor(private myElement: ElementRef) {
    this.elementRef = myElement;
  }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(event: Event): void {
    let clickedComponent = event.target;
    let inside = false;
    do {
      if (clickedComponent === this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
        inside = true;
        break;
      } else {
        clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;  <<<<====== see below
      }
    } while (clickedComponent);
    if(inside) {
      console.log('inside');
    } else {
      console.log('outside');
    }
  }
}
```

The test HTML:

```
<div>
  This is outside the workspace
</div>
<div shMonitorInfoClicks  [ngStyle]="{'height': '200px', 'width': '300px', 'border': '1px solid red'}">
  This is the workspace
  <div [ngStyle]="{'height': '100px', 'width': '100px', 'border': '1px solid green'}">
    A workspace child
  </div>
</div>
```

When I pause in the Chrome debugger, I am able to use the console to make parentNode or parentElement work.  However, I can't get past Typescript/Angular CLI.  I made sure I'm running the @latest Angular.  (It's 5).

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I can't get past Typescript/Angular CLI` What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event.target.parentNode` reference doesn't get past the compiler because the compiler is viewing `event.target` as an `EventTarget`, which doesn't have a `parentNode` property. In order to inform the compiler what your `event.target` really is, you need to [use a type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) to cast the `event.target` it's real type, which in your case is an `HTMLElement`:

```
const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
```

Now you will have access to `target.parentNode`.

The reason you are able to see it in the console is because that is printing out the `event.target` at runtime (types not included), but Angular's event object's `target` property returns something else. You can see a *little* more information here: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#type-the-event, but it's hard to find more information on it.

Anyways, you can always use the console to figure out what the type of your `event.target` really is and then cast your `event.target` to that type in the code. Then you can access all those properties you see in the console without the compiler throwing a fit :)

Comment: or `const target = <HTMLElement>event.target;` ? never used `as` keyword

Comment: @DrNio yes you can use that syntax too. I prefer the ‘as’ in this case, I find it more readable.